# how to create table and paste in libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, documentation

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and Libreoffice.I want to do some thing shown in this video 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rh7EQirZvoQ
using Libreoffice and Ubuntu.
I want to know how can I create table in libreoffice calc  and paste it to libreoffice writer.

Answer (score 0):

Download the OpenOffice extension named Pasteasvalue. Install it in LibreOffice using Tools menu--> Extension Manager.

Now when you copy any table from Calc you can paste it using the Pasteasvalue option from the Edit menu.

Comment: I googled the extension you said but it seems there is no such extension  I googled for "LibreOffice extension  Pasteasvalue" and the first link redirects me to http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/copy-only-visible-cells upon installing this pasting on libreoffice the cells lost their formatting no table borders came ,is this the extension or some thing wrong I did.